# PowerShell Script: Modify Users (HomeDirectory)

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm doing a virtual machine test, I have the following dilemma.

I want to modify a field to users who have HomeDirectory configured, for a new DFS path.

I have this script I does not work:

```
$user = Get-ADUser -Filter {HomeDirectory -like '*'} -Properties HomeDirectory | Select-Object  samaccountname

Set-ADUser -Identity $user -Replace @{homeDirectory="\\\mboulaayoun.com\comu\personals\$user"}
```

Comment: `"\\\mboulaayoun.com\comu\personals\$user"` -> `"\\mboulaayoun.com\comu\personals\$($user.SamAccountName)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys finnaly i get the correct way o do this, i hope can help someone with the same o similar problem.

```
 $user = Get-ADUser -Filter {HomeDirectory -like '*'} -Properties HomeDirectory, HomeDrive

foreach($e in $user)
{
    $name= $e.SamAccountName
    $drive = $e.HomeDrive
    Set-ADUser -Identity $name -HomeDirectory \\mboulaayoun.com\comu\personals\$nom -HomeDrive $drive 
}
```